# Android Studio can't find aapt in M preview

Tags: android, android-studio, aapt, android-6.0-marshmallow

You have the M preview channel build tools installed (at time of writing, rev 23rc1) and you get an error something like this:

```
Error:android-apt-compiler: 
Cannot run program ".../sdk/build-tools/23.0.0_rc1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

The build-tools binaries have moved (again)! You find them now under the bin directory.

```
$ ls build-tools/23.0.0_rc1/bin/
aapt                     arm-linux-androideabi-ld dexdump                  llvm-rs-cc               split-select
aidl                     bcc_compat               i686-linux-android-ld    mipsel-linux-android-ld  zipalign
```

So as a temporary fix, symlink them.

```
cd $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/23.0.0_rc1/
ln -s bin/* ./
```

Comment: Any idea where it's currently moved to? I've downloaded `platform-tools_r23-linux.zip`, and only find `adb` and `fastboot` binaries there.

Answer (score 0):

As you say the build-tools binaries have moved. So, a temporary fix is open the SDK Manager and remove the Tools of Preview Channel 23rc1 and make the 22.x version as default. Later Rebuild your project and done.

I hope this is useful.